# is there any way to add button into dropdown list with textfields using controlfx jar

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i have a textfield with autocomplete and i want to show button near each item appeared into that list

this is my code

```
 List<String> s = ms.getUsernames(ms.getUser(7).getListamis());
    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(txtsearch, s);
```

this is the method getusernames

```
      public List<String> getUsernames(String list_amis) {
       List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
       String [] idmember = list_amis.split("/");
        for (String i : idmember) {

            ls.add(getUser(Integer.parseInt(i)).getUsername());

    }
    return ls;
}
```

this is my output 
[image] 
i want to add a button near testing as a result i can get its ID

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with. There certainly is a better way that is more elegant and works better, but I guess this would work for many situations. You would have to do something about the size of the ListView, though, and I didn't test this in an environment in which the appearing ListView might change something about the design of the rest of the UI. I suggest putting the whole thing into a PopOver or something.

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class NewFXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("one","two","three");
        FilteredList<String> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(list);

        VBox box = new VBox();
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                filteredList.setPredicate(new Predicate<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(String s){
                        return s.toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.setItems(filteredList);
        listView.visibleProperty().bind(textField.textProperty().isNotEmpty());
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Object param) {
                ListCell cell = new ListCell(){
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty){
                        if(item != null && !empty){
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            HBox contentBox = new HBox();
                            Label label = new Label(item.toString());
                            Button button = new Button("delete");
                            HBox separator = new HBox();
                            HBox.setHgrow(separator, Priority.ALWAYS);
                            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                                @Override
                                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                                    System.out.println(item);
                                }
                            });
                            contentBox.getChildren().addAll(label, separator, button);
                            setGraphic(contentBox);
                        }else{
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
        box.getChildren().addAll(textField,listView);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(box);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Autocomplete");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thnks i'll try this